# Different definitions of commutator in operator theory/quantum mechanics vs. in group theory

Tags: operators, group-theory, commutator, lie-algebra

In group theory, the [commutator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Commutator) of two elements $g$ and $h$ in a group is defined as $$[g,h]=ghg^{-1}h^{-1}$$

However, in quantum mechanics, we always see commutator relation between two operators $A$ and $B$, which should belong to some group, to be defined as
$$[A,B]=AB-BA.$$
How to reconcile these two seemingly different definitions? I understand that operators in QM are in the Hilbert space, which has an additional vector space structure besides the group structure. However, since all vector spaces are groups, shouldn’t the vector space commutator also satisfy the group commutator definition?

Comment: A and B are in a Lie algebra, not a group. Their  Exponentials are in a group.

Comment: @CosmasZachos I see, thank you!

Comment: The [WP identity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Commutator#Exponential_identities) connecting your two commutators is the justification of utilizing the very same term for both objects. It is the very *essence* of Lie theory.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Operators form a **ring**, not a group. This is because the operator sum, $\hat{N} + \hat{O}$, makes sense, just as much as the operator composition or product, $\hat{N} \hat{O}$, and it satisfies all the usual properties.

The commutator definition used in quantum theory is the ring commutator.

The group-theoretic definition only works if the objects in question are invertible, since you need to take their $-1$th compositional power. Group elements must be invertible by definition. But there is no stipulation that all quantum operators must be invertible - e.g. projection operators are, essentially by definition, *not* so.

Comment: I see, thank you!

Comment: @Leo L. : Yep, and if you want to see an operator sum in action, look no further than the Hamiltonian operator in the usual mechanical Schrodinger equation: $\hat{H} = \hat{K} + \hat{U}$.

Answer (score 1):

Consider the relationship between the automorphism group of a vector space and its Lie algebra of linear operators.

Let $X,Y$ be linear operators, and consider their exponentials $e^{tX}$ and $e^{tY}$. Assuming these series converge (they always do for finite-dimensional vector spaces), then $e^{-tX}e^{tX}=e^{tX}e^{-tX}=I$, so exponentiating linear operators produces automorphisms of your vector space.

To avoid any convergence issues with the above series, we'll take the input $t$ to be so small that it is a nilsquare infinitesimal (i.e. $t^2 = 0$). This infinitesimal approach is made rigorous in [smooth infinitesimal analysis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Smooth_infinitesimal_analysis) (also known as [synthetic differential geometry](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Synthetic_differential_geometry)).

Let $\delta_1, \delta_2$ be nilsquare infinitesimals, i.e. $\delta_1^2=\delta_2^2=0$ (Note: in general, $\delta_1 \delta_2 \neq 0$.). Then the higher order terms in both power series vanish and we are left with

$$e^{\delta_1 X} = I + \delta_1 X,$$
$$e^{\delta_2 Y} = I + \delta_2 Y.$$

Thus, with some simple algebra we can easily show that the group theoretic commutator of the automorphism group reproduces the Lie algebra commutator of the linear operators. I'd recommend trying it for yourself, as it's pretty satisfying to see the result come out:

$$[e^{\delta_1 X},e^{\delta_2 Y}]= e^{\delta_1 X}e^{\delta_2 Y}(e^{\delta_2 Y}e^{\delta_1 X})^{-1}=I + \delta_1 \delta_2 [X,Y].$$